# How do I select/stroke multiple paths at once in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, stroke

Just as it says in the title. I have multiple paths and I'd like them all to have the same stroke.

Answer (score 6):

Seems like it's not possible to select multiple paths. Operations can only be done on one path at once. So the solution is to merge the paths of interest; perhaps they belong together anyway.

In the [Paths Dialog](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-path-dialog.html),

1. Make all paths of interest visible, and make all other paths invisible.
2. Right click > Merge Visible Paths

Comment: Indeed. One alternative would be to create a script to duplicate and merge all existig paths - and the stroke operation would then be performed on this duplicated, disposable, super-path.